# My CSS menus hidden behind iframe with flash

Tags: html, css, flash, menu

my css drop down menu is hidden behind a flash element I have on my site. I have tried changing the z index but still nothing. Please help.... here is the page. www.cougarguide.com

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set the transparency for your embedded object:

```
<object>
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">​
   <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" ... />​
</object>
```

Comment: I changed the "wmode" in the param but can't find the embed type. www.cougarguide.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the window mode of your swf to transparent. Here is a link : http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the window mode will happen. That just makes the flash background transparent.

You have a different issue - the menu is below the flash. I looked at the code, and it seems like you are using an iframe with whole new html wrapper. I don't know how you made that website, but the menu div comes AFTER the div that loads the iframe. Swap those and you should be good to go.

If that code is generated by something, try figuring out how to generate the menu first and then that div that loads the flash.

hope that helps

Comment: "I don't know how you made that website, but the menu div comes AFTER the div that loads the iframe. Swap those and you should be good to go."  What exactly would I swap?

Comment: You have a div with id='Nav'. It comes AFTER another div with id="Layer25". Bring the Nav div with everything in it, before the div named Layer25.  

Also, those divs have absolute positioning. This is not recommended for layouts. position:absolute is used mostly to fix small things and make items pop out of a box, for example, the map icon on the bottom of this page: http://www.twogears.com

Comment: ok I put Nav div at the very top but still having the same problem... also should I set the divs to relative?

Comment: You should definitely NOT use absolute positioning. Very bad practice. If you decide to redo the site, you will see how everything is hanging mid air. That means for example that if you ever have longer or shorter text, nothing will realign, or take it into consideration, and things will start hiding behind other things.

Comment: But to be honest I don't know what exactly is going on, might be something with javascripts, there's quite a lot of them

Comment: so relative is the way to go?